# Nothing compiles after cleanup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

I'm writing a C++ wxWidgets calculator application. I recently started getting some random IntelliSense errors that did not however stop compilation. I followed an advice online and performed Clean Solution after deleting the `.suo` file in my project directory. Now I'm getting 92 errors that do however interrupt compilation, and I have no idea what to do.

[image]

[image]

"Cannot open error code ".." of source file

[image]

Cannot open inclusion file: ".." no setup.h such file or directory

And lots of other erros of these kinds, along with random syntax errors.

I think that the problem might be that VS isn't finding `wx/wx.h` for some reason.

**My setup (don't know if it has anything to do with the errors)**

To start programming with wxWidgets, I followed a YT tutorial. I have my wxWidgets files in my D: disk. I have a WXWIN system variable pointing to that directory. In Project properties > C/C++ > General > Additional include directories I have `$(WXWIN)\include; $(WXWIN)\include\msvc`. Then, in Linker > General > Additional library directories I have `$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib`.

After Clean Solution these options were reset to default (along with `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` preprocessor) and I had to re-enter them. Now I'm getting all these errors and I don't know what to do.

Comment: The settings are different for different configuration (Debug/Release) and platform (Win32/x64). Make sure you configuration and platform of the settings you edit correspond to the configuration and platform you are building.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you simply didn't build wxWidgets itself in x64 release configuration that you use. You must do it before using it.

I also strongly recommend following the [official installation instructions](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.5/overview_install.html) rather than tutorials that may be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I accidentally changed the combo box left of the "Local windows debugger" button from x86 to x64. I switched it back to x86 (even if I don't know what that means) and everything is back as it is.